# how to insert array input from txtfield in php

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to insert data from a form to database , however it gives lots of error notices.

`Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\thesis\admin\gov_sched_save.php on line 181`

A lot of this error notices in different lines.

This is the form structure[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzYkj.png)

and the code for the form (just the snippet for the part I find confusing):

```
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="margin-right:-10px">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Time</th>
                            <th>M</th>
                            <th>T</th>
                            <th>W</th>
                            <th>Th</th>
                            <th>F</th>

                          </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <?php
               include('dbcon.php');
                $query=mysql_query("select * from time where days='mtwthf' order by time_in")or die(mysql_error());

            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                    $id=$row['time_id'];
                    $start=date("h:i a",strtotime($row['time_in']));
                    $end=date("h:i a",strtotime($row['time_out']));
    ?>
                          <tr >
                            <td><?php echo $start."-".$end;?></td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="check" name="m[]" value="<?php echo $id;?>" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;"><input style="width: 150px;" type="text" placeholder="Post Area" name="area[]"></td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="check" name="t[]" value="<?php echo $id;?>" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;"><input style="width: 150px;" type="text" placeholder="Post Area" name="area[]"></td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="check" name="w[]" value="<?php echo $id;?>" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;"><input style="width: 150px;" type="text" placeholder="Post Area" name="area[]"></td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="check" name="th[]" value="<?php echo $id;?>" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;"><input style="width: 150px;" type="text" placeholder="Post Area" name="area[]"></td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="check" name="f[]" value="<?php echo $id;?>" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;"><input style="width: 150px;" type="text" placeholder="Post Area" name="area[]"></td>

                          </tr>

    <?php }?>   

    </table>    
    </div><!--col end -->
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="daterange-btn" name="submit" type="submit">
                 Save Schedule
                </button>
```

This is the php part wherein the errors came from. And probably the root of the malfunctioning of the code.
This part is the insert query:

```
     <?php 
include('dbcon.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$month = $_POST['month'];
$guard = $_POST['guard_id'];
$area = $_POST['area']; 
$time = $_POST['time_id'];

$m = $_POST['m'];
$t = $_POST['t'];
$w = $_POST['w'];
$th = $_POST['th'];
$f = $_POST['f'];




  //monday sched
  foreach ($m as $daym){
    //check conflict
    $query=mysql_query("select *,COUNT(*) as count from gov_sched 
    natural join member natural join time where guard_id='$guard' and gov_sched.time_id='$daym' and area='$area' 
    and day='m' and month='$month'")or die(mysql_error());
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
        $count=$row['count'];
        $time1=date("h:i a",strtotime($row['time_in']))."-".date("h:i a",strtotime($row['time_out']));
        $guard1=$row['lastname']." ".$row['firstname'];
        $area1=$row['area'];

    $queryt=mysql_query("select * from member where member_id='$guard'")or die(mysql_error());
            $rowt=mysql_fetch_array($queryt);
            $guardt=$rowt['lastname']." ".$rowt['firstname'];

    $querytime=mysql_query("select * from time where time_id='$daym'")or die(mysql_error($con));
            $rowt=mysql_fetch_array($querytime);
            $timet=date("h:i a",strtotime($rowt['time_in']))."-".date("h:i a",strtotime($rowt['time_out']));    


    if ($count==0)
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO gov_sched(month,guard_id,area,time_id,day) VALUES ('$month','$guard','$area','$daym','m')")or die(mysql_error());

        echo "<span class='text-success'>$month $timet $guardt at $area every Monday successfully added!</span><br>";   
    }           
    else{

        echo "<span class='text-danger'>$month $time1 is already taken by $guard1 at $area every Monday </span><br>";

    }

}


    foreach ($t as $dayt){
    //check conflict
    $query=mysql_query("select *,COUNT(*) as count from gov_sched 
    natural join member natural join time where guard_id='$guard' and gov_sched.time_id='$dayt' and area='$area' 
    and day='t' and month='$month'")or die(mysql_error());
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
        $count=$row['count'];
        $time1=date("h:i a",strtotime($row['time_in']))."-".date("h:i a",strtotime($row['time_out']));
        $guard1=$row['lastname']." ".$row['firstname'];
        $area1=$row['area'];

    $queryt=mysql_query("select * from member where member_id='$guard'")or die(mysql_error());
            $rowt=mysql_fetch_array($queryt);
            $guardt=$rowt['lastname']." ".$rowt['firstname'];

    $querytime=mysql_query("select * from time where time_id='$dayt'")or die(mysql_error($con));
            $rowt=mysql_fetch_array($querytime);
            $timet=date("h:i a",strtotime($rowt['time_in']))."-".date("h:i a",strtotime($rowt['time_out']));    


    if ($count==0)
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO gov_sched(month,guard_id,area,time_id,day) VALUES ('$month','$guard','$area','$dayt','t')")or die(mysql_error());

        echo "<span class='text-success'>$month $timet $guardt at $area every Tuesday successfully added!</span><br>";  
    }           
    else{

        echo "<span class='text-danger'>$month $time1 is already taken by $guard1 at $area every Tuesday </span><br>";

    }

}

        foreach ($w as $dayw){
    //check conflict
    $query=mysql_query("select *,COUNT(*) as count from gov_sched 
    natural join member natural join time where guard_id='$guard' and gov_sched.time_id='$dayw' and area='$area' 
    and day='w' and month='$month'")or die(mysql_error());
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
        $count=$row['count'];
        $time1=date("h:i a",strtotime($row['time_in']))."-".date("h:i a",strtotime($row['time_out']));
        $guard1=$row['lastname']." ".$row['firstname'];
        $area1=$row['area'];

    $queryt=mysql_query("select * from member where member_id='$guard'")or die(mysql_error());
            $rowt=mysql_fetch_array($queryt);
            $guardt=$rowt['lastname']." ".$rowt['firstname'];

    $querytime=mysql_query("select * from time where time_id='$dayw'")or die(mysql_error($con));
            $rowt=mysql_fetch_array($querytime);
            $timet=date("h:i a",strtotime($rowt['time_in']))."-".date("h:i a",strtotime($rowt['time_out']));    


    if ($count==0)
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO gov_sched(month,guard_id,area,time_id,day) VALUES ('$month','$guard','$area','$dayw','w')")or die(mysql_error());

        echo "<span class='text-success'>$month $timet $guardt at $area every Wednesday successfully added!</span><br>";    
    }           
    else{

        echo "<span class='text-danger'>$month $time1 is already taken by $guard1 at $area every Wednesday </span><br>";

    }

}


            foreach ($th as $dayth){
    //check conflict
    $query=mysql_query("select *,COUNT(*) as count from gov_sched 
    natural join member natural join time where guard_id='$guard' and gov_sched.time_id='$dayth' and area='$area' 
    and day='th' and month='$month'")or die(mysql_error());
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
        $count=$row['count'];
        $time1=date("h:i a",strtotime($row['time_in']))."-".date("h:i a",strtotime($row['time_out']));
        $guard1=$row['lastname']." ".$row['firstname'];
        $area1=$row['area'];

    $queryt=mysql_query("select * from member where member_id='$guard'")or die(mysql_error());
            $rowt=mysql_fetch_array($queryt);
            $guardt=$rowt['lastname']." ".$rowt['firstname'];

    $querytime=mysql_query("select * from time where time_id='$dayth'")or die(mysql_error($con));
            $rowt=mysql_fetch_array($querytime);
            $timet=date("h:i a",strtotime($rowt['time_in']))."-".date("h:i a",strtotime($rowt['time_out']));    


    if ($count==0)
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO gov_sched(month,guard_id,area,time_id,day) VALUES ('$month','$guard','$area','$dayth','th')")or die(mysql_error());

        echo "<span class='text-success'>$month $timet $guardt at $area every Thursday successfully added!</span><br>"; 
    }           
    else{

        echo "<span class='text-danger'>$month $time1 is already taken by $guard1 at $area every Thursday </span><br>";

    }

}

                foreach ($f as $dayf){
    //check conflict
    $query=mysql_query("select *,COUNT(*) as count from gov_sched 
    natural join member natural join time where guard_id='$guard' and gov_sched.time_id='$dayf' and area='$area' 
    and day='f' and month='$month'")or die(mysql_error());
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
        $count=$row['count'];
        $time1=date("h:i a",strtotime($row['time_in']))."-".date("h:i a",strtotime($row['time_out']));
        $guard1=$row['lastname']." ".$row['firstname'];
        $area1=$row['area'];

    $queryt=mysql_query("select * from member where member_id='$guard'")or die(mysql_error());
            $rowt=mysql_fetch_array($queryt);
            $guardt=$rowt['lastname']." ".$rowt['firstname'];

    $querytime=mysql_query("select * from time where time_id='$dayf'")or die(mysql_error($con));
            $rowt=mysql_fetch_array($querytime);
            $timet=date("h:i a",strtotime($rowt['time_in']))."-".date("h:i a",strtotime($rowt['time_out']));    


    if ($count==0)
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO gov_sched(month,guard_id,area,time_id,day) VALUES ('$month','$guard','$area','$dayf','f')")or die(mysql_error());

        echo "<span class='text-success'>$timet $guardt at $area every Friday successfully added!</span><br>";  
    }           
    else{

        echo "<span class='text-danger'>$time1 is already taken by $guard1 at $area every Friday </span><br>";

    }

}

  }
     ?>
```

The thing is I dont know if I was wrong in the html form structure or in the php side. I find it really confusing.

the fields for the `area` field in the database is forcedly storing the word Array in it.

Comment: You may want to elaborate on some of those errors, it is hard for people to guess. In the meanwhile I can't imagine that a print_r($_POST) to make sure of what is actually in it could hurt.

Comment: It's a lot of Notice array to string conversion errors. @deg

Comment: Now if you could point out what that particular line in the error looks like...

Comment: It is in every select query and insert query of every for each loop where there is `$area` variable. generally it is in the php code I think.\

Comment: So that $area is an array, and you are trying to write it in the db as a string. Is it MEANT to be an array ?

Comment: You're right @deg I want to write it in the db as string. That is where I am confused right now. I am confused if it is in the form I amwrong or in the php side.

Comment: It is an array because you are posting name="area[]", which means "all these inputs are values of the array area". Is that what it's meant to be ? There are ways to turn arrays into strings - is that what you aim for ?

Comment: yes @deg that's what I'm aiming. But don't know how.

Comment: For starters you could print_r($area) to see what's in it. Debugging is a non conditional side skill of coding. See if implode("_", $area); looks like what you want.

Comment: would you mind showing me how to do it? And why is it if I used name="area" it does not include if I add records in the db it's an empty field.?

Comment: You can't have multiple inputs with the same name in the DOM, they conflict. If you get anything, you would get the value of the last "area" input to be rendered. And there is nothing in html part of the code where you assign a value to these "area" inputs after the query.

Comment: so how should I overcome it?I just wanna get this to work.

Comment: <input style="width: 150px;" type="text" placeholder="Post Area" name="area[]"> As you can see you don't assign them a value, like you do for the checkboxes just before.

Comment: I tried print the `$area` but it only displays the last 2 values I entered.

Comment: I doesnt work man @deg

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153579/post-how-to-insert-array-input-from-txtfield-in-php